# UK Plug Adapter for LED light

Tags: power-supply, connector, led-driver, adapter

I bought an LED lamp from Germany and it arrived with an EU plug and a UK adapter. I don't really want to use an adapter on it all the time fixed in my home (And also, the adapter they sent actually doesn't work with this style of plug).

Something I haven't seen before, the light cable terminates with a connector, and then the plug is attached to the end of it via another connector.

[image]

I'm not familiar with the type of connector it is. It seems to be a fairly standard barrel, but with some sort of locking mechanism that locks it into the cable.

[image]

The plug itself says it is an LED Controlgear, with a Max output of 23Vdc, Max 10W, 6V... 20Vdc, Constant 500mA.

[image]

My question is:

Is there something special about this adapter/connector for the LED light? The word "Controlgear" make me wonder if this is doing something more than a standard adapter? Or could I buy an adapter with the right barrel and 10W, 6V and plug it in?

(Or, even better, is this a standard locking barrel for LED lights, and can I just pick up one somewhere?)

Answer (score 4):

10W 6V will probably not light your lamp

this is a constant current supply instead of a constant voltage supply, so you'll need to find a similar DC constant current supply.

Answer (score 2):

## Plug

I suggest plug type is 5.5x2.5 barrel jack. Fairly popular and useful kind of connector you can see everywhere, even disassemble from old equipment or broken power supply. To avoid soldering, you can buy this  type of plug. Be cearfull not confusing it with 5.5x2.1 jack. (2.1mm wount feet (see the picute)).
[image: Solder free jack]
[image: Types of barred jacks]

## Power supply

With power supply, it is a little more tricky. You have not voltage but 500mA constant current supply. So, you need either buy one like this, or connect it and measure exact voltage it is providing to buy voltage supply. There is a more clever way to calculate voltage, but for it, you need to know characteristics of a strip you want to power.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a UK housing, with UK plug-pins, for the innards of your EU wall-wart

[example](https://www.rapidonline.com/Evatron-FE4-UK-Small-13A-Plug-PSU-Case-30-3205)

These things are often glued or welded together so you'll likely have to *very carefully* apply a rotary tool or mini-hacksaw to your EU wall-wart to extract the PCB without damaging any electronics parts.

You can re-use the locking cable, even if you have to chop it off and strip new ends.

Comment: very carefully applying a vise or hammer tends to work for me.